# NextJS how to get audio file from HttpService that is playable?

Tags: typescript, axios, nestjs

I'm trying to receive a simple MP3 audio file from an HttpService using Axios and NestJS. I successfully receive audio data from the HTTPService but I guess I use the wrong format in FileController or FileService (or both). When I save the received data manually (Via Postman) to a file and name it to "file.mp3", the length of the audio is zero but it shouldn't. The API says

> If the HTTP status is 200 OK, the body of the response contains an audio file in the requested format. This file can be played as it's transferred, saved to a buffer, or saved to a file.

What I have tried so far is to change the header with @Response but without success.

```
getFile(@Response() res: Res): Res {
        
        const result = this.fileService.getFile(getFileDto)
        return res.set({ 'content-type': 'audio/mpeg' }).attachment(result)
    }
```

Response header:

```
connection: keep-alive 
 content-length: 70996 
 content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 
 date: Wed,20 Apr 2022 15:59:31 GMT 
 etag: W/"11554-BSClKp7ZxyboIt5RNQ/MWP0JC48" 
 keep-alive: timeout=5 
 x-powered-by: Express
```

Response body:

```
����HLAME3.100UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUULAME3.100UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU0�w1Yc�g;0c�.8��Z24�3]#5�#_2S�D�4-��N�n.cC�QQ�!��2!2'p�\0͏1�$�   ��AN�pa�h�*��3��M��J�K$�I" ��$XP����c��PFxv3v<�*1lEV��u�JsN�B�}��lb؎(#1�
��f̙�H`S����ıy,h޲��0���P���>I���=@)Ϯ6��\���0�)��B�њ"�mϙF�   8���j�t7b�q�6|�A:�/CN�����R`P�蚥�,�T�U
#J�L;���Vh��:f�5�d�����$FPp���Lt�an�HU �1���L����9m�H�:�8H��*̂䐌b$�@`8�Ji���P�
�LdM�[Ҁ�1"�]�,��*�
H�<��<�1Ɗ`D O
�a���(1�OUL���V'ڿd�<��[rqYk.Y����� ���� ��
��6���LAME3.100������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������� `����&�]�bo����FXN��m��Ps��7���ba��  ?����%�C
�X�2
4a�!��4���$��f�LC���&�2�
|�}�*��%8�4�,�`I�fl&� ��B!  �J܀�`�1�`�8�<3�*�[`V��!�h���ěs��$�D��#N4�䄜0�P���ά�I����1���k�aPQ���Ǿ�#P`�c32���x3�s�S@�nQ���1�Ɔ7�>OKp��,��I=R�PA�(ІZ�P��>`�\���%��Q�����G����>���rA�9&2�H2�� �A�m��L�-��    1Q/��*ka�S�,�ҧI0B'�&�I��P��B��L@0A�`@�eFa��yf��W��T�\!N���Z'���q��h���
�hnϕ�%����dQ4����ԍ&��
�LAME3.100UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU�x��B�x����
�賎��L�8.k��B�40�cc�8�9�����x���(8�^A'�P37F+Hpx5�x�+9�Mp\�q�&���FlZ�����i���A�Xn̋;1�����"x1h��r��P���d8�TÇ40Q�(�d)�<" e]6!���ıy<�޳���3�L�P4S������c�S��#
! g��!qb��C��&N#
j�9���  $��)1��`cu����̀�0 :��"!<*N:g� @)�4�|ĵfaA�GC�9�&�(���@@�X<�6*&ehU�i�h���^���y2cԁE@P��@+�
�%,
" B"����DI�Y�q�a�ppHz64C��Qw    L�A7��1�,��#(�G9�
{���f��.�����A8(Ⱥ��|�@+(�o�shד4 W!=?Y�2�5j_�D�>�R�Ɯe�cE�)�&��LAME3.100�������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������2A��`�x���+�x*8���/cB�D��g/|�c#с�`�\0d1���%P���#&��Q�K&�3�,8 �ư��0�#�8�TT��Zg�
�
�4`�
[�àV� A�g(r�0C�C���5ԃ�a�@@ā�&
^�.�d`A{���ĕr<�5\�Q���%`$&��C%C�#�\-�6e�V�����iXA"�IDA��Z�8(��!�Bł��J-2�ZC
r�R���3
:@���ڱk�H=N�4F=lP��<��bɤ]�l�jF�-k>}ڢ}�t-C��P<��Ĩ�C�d��غ�Yiw
�NΙJ��<�l�[v���B�"�PĶv&Y3<aka�+��,2�a ���"�(��v��R&R�-48��"��U��(b��uܨ  o��:�.P�IR���0���n[�M��Ɂ����K�2*� $��R�CLAME3.100UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU P@;�l`@xeQ``��dk ��X�4�u��<)����P��Y\��a Ȃ����U<�T��僾�����*��&
G,�gOF�g
T��k��s%�)�^�#��C�3��}v9�S;�j`�����x���Ęr�D����S�S��P*�+;L�̚.LjJh�l�ԣ��@ ��(     !�@�P%
&�@ �#0890\(q�dbJ�cjY&0�(�FA�A���� cp�`Hb1
axX`h�bA#B�i��y��̞��j��1�v)D��D&���@�
�.��F6�Հ�a�à�AtĠ���!H������h���!��������<��nF�'m��6��gÒ�)��Wi���+-�ӹ.�+�s���������%�Db�0�E!�")"��9��w�5Ʋ�Q��v}يȎ���za�TٕLAME3.100UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUMe�]hx�@!04�O1�  S�y0�   ��90Js�0;�%�� P&��������N����,��&���(/��XA�`:�� .�p�*�A���q�T�h�"���`!������\̄x� �4�D¨&C��h��˸�J�@�@4D#A4F�����|�L�����:"@� ʖd���"�j��6\��ٖ��`�:��(�e/� [€
��
�>"$<L��&
0��€
@8( U���d\�&.��D� ����P��� �Y�������� ��T�)���-��x�LtxK�
��MAd@JH��#��T������X�?�*��¼��MT��=�^5k
Kr)m7k�IhHcJY
1��<�C���OKf19-��$�w�����=z����Zi��Y�XFs����ȫ�Z�
gO/�D-*LAME3.100����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������cІ�
FL
�
��`��$�$a2& �`u���C����Z���8&��aV$�w�Ld�F`���`�0NaD����ٞ%F 'Y��"��2ch�§�&u��A   p���$�Rh.�@�
AF9N����Čo�P�2�k�A�Q�*#\^b�a��f.8�1R$V4Pp��R��N2`X�$84�~pwc��«1z��!��2�0を^Ac(�dL��U��(Sl����.���:rTPt��)�1��k]X!�RcM�Pu2(�$"TCI#���D�(�JRH� J5�A�0@�X1
��e)��Ћ���e�u$ݹ�9��a�{��Ԛ���ݐU}H���ȴF/iU#)���^�,�csnM�
��V&d2�m�ޒD,C��%3�o�
h�aܜeN��rf�����(:۰���I�v��QI��ՊW�LAME3.100UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUy��uw  �(���c™I�0{���a���#��%��a�q��*��L����,*LE
���
�`K��)0�Ѹ3��&%� y���I�%YtS>L�?H��@X$������gJfB�F6`^���ėr�L��`sAt8��r,4���S0�@��f�1a����pP�
$�)̹���
v�62&�M��4����U!bHm��   W.j���Yy�,}ƃ�� �€ˁC~G�`��40�u�(lX�B'(�p�n!�P�,�]��[����f����p�Ě0��M��X�_�tbA���ּ�!Ȍ��E��r|���9A2Н8  �8�w�tVL�-�ŝV���n0xV�SU��Kw�X��1G��7Z�`գ���}�\Yk�R7F�k�i�.vZ�ۋgSN���Z�����z��LAME3.100�������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������ǔA���\���nǳ"\a�$�!`ap�@�a�9f�#a��!`l   � $������@�/@�%��48L@0P�����Π�8!���
e�`+�J��Zw�)ܰ��jx\�����ąnH���������)T}�������(0]�#(Nd32b2�c��7Fe&8b�/3HC1d�>V<6�0�dh(X�Ђ�B"�� bĀ����X@ɒ8��$L` �
�eP�X��D�J�J(H�F�C��Fn�t!��R�J��e�䞤����(�w@�D<��Z�%��28k%�Xd�.�v�q=�w$r���f�#��3@��KB_)�W{�1����F�8�t����a�;���ʦ��ߨ�>����E"5���
�Xr_���t�M+����H���q�n�E"�?��c��J�ULAME3.100UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU�8�B`e��`0!�v�8�+�s0�2Hp`*�d�elL0�h
�0`@
&�`0��e
�&$l` " (�(b@ɔ���ę��,�l�P���-44E��˙MKX  -�@k
-�����Q����ďp�J�6�Hu����\|^1���C�T\�AGH��aB6$a�&6VjN`ACF8B�n3Ds;04szU!�@�.����fr� ��S
!��qA`r9�&�.0��H�4����*�*���5/E$ߔ�C�%�~�Tל���k:N��0�2����d�a�
�ē��lW���/fgd��2k2�t�*��
y�3'�z/8�O�Vc�w@+
�H �~�)}g"�Ttr%�������vmEe�w�R�K�1I��ŸLJ-ۚ�V���3�٬nLλMjT�R�J�DyˆAo�r��ߺ�#y*LAME3.100���������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������Lvn�`&�btF���c�tFC`�g�!�Ab�-f%�df`�&tA�a"D&`bf \b(&4`Zg�jfXb�% ��0#�y0(  1z���s.0Q1��N�3<�E2��>!0p�z�>�6O��`�l�N����ēq�4��9��CMz�
�ɂL�P͖̙����"\���E@PT�3�b{6$�>72aT��9���($(c��@���Y-I��A�<j��D��BS=�*(��,RnR<���dK�4�t UV#Js�QoYs
_��<����!����s[
�<��(r%��@Ȋ.�����̂'�$P�
%�)�R+�8y���b��ݛ���vZ�Jb�D=1�׉�<�[�pqr�{9��B�>0��J����*,pg�kB�����즂�NY��™��-���V�=%�J�QŰ�-����笥R�VLAME3.100���������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������� ʀ�`��)T`'>`O�8a�xi@aK�`m`��4`���`N`ɇ&f&�h�ѷKF@,�Mf0�`w�ɼ� �PLd0��&7��hC���p\��02��p��
�0���
�M���`1p�Bf!i�g���Ĕr0��4��  ��� 4a#!��Xk��p�5*̐�!��
d��q� ��;βc%!h��2��������3 ,h�Lň�7�ك*jY�nsL��8�c�"�iQd���A3EM/��`M�ӟ�r�ݚYs��@o��N�M!���k@"�4�K|�c�@ ��5�
Į�v�M�%m�G��R�WL�����V�#\�����F�t����k���ci��*�3�c��@+��C���G�k��2�9LEh�����/nRy�D�Q&��Q/A�m��#DH��=���Q����4�U�z)��H�LAME3.100���������������������������������������������������������������������������������8@рT進�����zق:��zL�<!(s|���+����ȍ�&#`��h���p*#�#�c��
 P&xfp��>o�&�
H��b���|i!�d��!"C7D�<%W2�l3��x:Y#�8�����ĥvD_�����V����� ��H|<^a�`�4�<1�8����t0t-�",b �!&��%�A1��
���
0��!��JB�
�P�ٳ��ٱ�jA�.����8ą�(�).}��-�/:od�^��G�ɫ@r���] ,Q���j� �r�l�b��`4`i�P(yƥi��.���G'��T�v�����T4�^(ԕ[b��W/UU}�'b�)*W�} ���������g����V����4Ġ�jt��9p��!�!M�ǁ\�ȫ:G��V�[�>�����C�J{P̶e�LAME3.100�������������������������������������������������������������0��G.�0�!��0�#�cz=O�D!�:�#4v2���7��Q�4��@E1\!#��6��6�2@=�#&�d-�p�f��&����$���
�����$�q�X4L��%C���0�=���T`�2.>����9a���tZ��ml,��dH�bY*f8�o�<i����Ĺ{��\J�O�Ht t��;���T��sw��CK�#Z�Bu��d2����0f����Zj��ö�},~
�4L�5P͑v͵4Npd�X-��!M�b���}@|��rY���o�b�N4��.���\@�?��c'�C\�s1�SA�,�-US[K�o*Y벮V�brj՟�Z�$6�w%�(.\����ˡ9L^�3��\$��7��(��-���:��8̥
��=��������9M�;�?�V��_
)e]��{ֹ���6�����
�����a���0À(�P��p��@3@�E6�LAME3.100UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU��Q�������  R]��g�9�
�fa�d$��    ����9�A�!�H�:)#�FVY��D<��@!d��#^Oq��D`0�?P"��y�x-�ak�Bf zfDf 
41��!4W�U%��L���C&M-����L`b�8ac�
\Z#���LX���Ľ|DLA���PL�(8o�@BS$�ٵ��i�Iǀ��J�(D
2����A��3@�0㰢��#�I�ƒ�&,e`�@���Qq��ai��F���,*`�P&�9��3��{�8Y���ц��P�8x�<h�Ã�$x1(�B���0 �IJ��D    �x8��FL@9�a����br@0h X4�ŧ(Q@�!�����`aA�f
D1U�$ ]8N����� �qu(^NL9M�����f�"�R��1�{�a«.��Z�NՅ������k����l�����LAME3.100UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU*(X�@���32��}��sô�L*���@"�����
>ŐL@L @d�!&��o� ���$L�H E�[`������85�l� ,�����4�Fl��e��Xu�{e̙���/��)c
b�IZ����b5�tÓ��16����@"�������PB0!P��������h�1�����}d0��`�P��`�Ac�F84Xg@�Z13*
2�4��
1�!�3��:;9��� H@,q�!f�$gBb&C&/5���2�*0Ҁ8t:B@e�!�@I����  ���V�T<
@n`�"$�N�6(W!1q�/�
����c���P3  0�0�#G�-32bS!@��@`���Q��I*    ��P L|P ��(�i�P��
P�#�vR-5���q�����T.J���Y���N�q{tBMM@Rɋq8��N��RN���i��LAME3.100UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUhe�0#050t#p>�<��0�@02����x���y�h��D� `R��Y�x'8���(�Р��X
���p�`$0X���P�Q��   l�7Cg�s[pH���j���UH,�㯥�0��+Y��B�#����F�Q�A�� ,IЩ��#���I1�q���n�~a���`�1�����}D4�4���'��e��K�WM�C1����FC�JhA�    B�0`�!�B3   ��� �B0��1�ţc2�
Y2��C�3��!2�PSG@��B*e�1��D������j�6h�9��k�.cP8е9
���|����!٣��?Ⱦ���2^&z)��)$�� �.̬1�y��.UZY� eE�C����y~@���`�$�`l
�h(9M�h
�|ҙrΔ�z%6U�J7�V,�S�~l��:�&���j�h�:������kߍ{�Uˌ=�V�.��$Ԛ��LAME3.100UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU`0�@�`��0�1<Lћ��l&�A�Haj$p�rj��"`��@�`��°en �
�`/��%
�b�5�B/���`� Xf���hh����0�`�Av�k�V�
�|�(�#
��R���f!lf�����$p��F����Ķzl9��6��"
��6Y���@�8FaR��d�!��`@`(.
�bdF��
�:'��(2Y�ӆS��t-�C�3���l��"`ŀs
,4:a D��X\$,�"0e3E!p�PȜ�PFAC-9�`jb��A�|�(
d��P��c)��^A��@ԋ?!EP�R,��[���z')ȓ�2��JDA�#�bM(`<hV��
���!f�]v���q��rf^�t��0�!K��7(l���O�zI9s��ĩ���8D���NKe�4���jQF$nĳ    Tn��y�Ζ+wl���n������bLAME3.100�����������������������������������������������������������01C�0��"A�>�B�!<0:��[����>�1���0LĬ�iL����D�(����P��#*0�4�@�*ȁ�7�rb�m 0@`ʦsK�@`��b�XBL�1�G&g���zR0�4�#3-#
],4餘�@1Q8��#gP}&s�,v`qٔI�{���Ļ{�0^�
��d����3    LT01�Ƞ���u���zA2�=�0`(Tdd⁠�F���`��Mz�8l�㯣U-LN)̢_3J����C��t8Ja�1��X$\Lާr����,�EVL�   �� !�X��тA&��S)Ĩ�l�x)����dU �(b`�B̆� "G���qa��e90�׬�z+�ҋߍ�j:lVS��˄���1�,�H��DHn�?���)A@��-�a���)����_h��-�n�-t"
6�m�8����?�Y��,�����+T��g�-W����F[LAME3.100UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUF@|��}\�]I���D��l��r� C��eLx����xX� �Ml���yL?@���H��GD�sz���� d8J'�F"���_ �Xİ��P�08�"��@rZ�5�(��"1�
�"* B��h�Z���(4t    
Y+���C@���  ^h�nb�\e���Ŀ|�@�����~A�#Av`q44�XGXĒ���ƈ4
�,�/6\:����rH0@����҄ ��C
����`�
$��;���
�� $�k��$@�b�p@8a$\�0`0��l�@�x/�Њ_a`yU�(8kjd˙�5���A�
t3��N$�o�I(���{�V���<o��d�^��^W�YcR���Sى"��b�Qߑ��   �C/��c,R�3i�r>$5�   �/[.�NL�gEQC���xvK�5.��<¬���Z�1-��{Y�LAME3.100��������������������������������������������������������������lS�4iʀ`ZT&N"�aDfk��`X0�A`�`��+�BcBfĜ`4��V`H`�,��c�7C�`�!&�@����0�@#�`d��>��`P�� 
c�0@��s���� �@T��B��2a

A�P,*04��,�@#���Ļ{�X����0�B�>L��\
Tİ4�
@l�lL@�,    ��,�����x�tLd��� H<�$��X��� ��@8@M�lU`�,����04�+����\��
�A�L%�.�    p��\0(%�BL�0Х4��Y�?
�ZܢWV����hcm2��b)ݵ����G��[�ȄK   �1J���1�-�C��+�,l��ؼ��}VH�+��u�9]�n��:��v��F    ���
�*׻�'c��2�^�f��i��;6�v���LAME3.100UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU+��`��0&��0e�r�0� `����Ls�0���Lt�T€�����9O��|�L�T�C����,L"C�̈eL
�0�����L�>;ǜ��Â�s9���:2�U�:+3Y�Ƭ�o-�F"vd���9�fa@I���6
pr���ĢuT@�����b�� P*�4B��@eV�h2`B9����k�*��M�]�8-���f�10s��a���*u�1ɐ�!���6��N8��^��GԼ0��3_T�A �iz�*�
R`�=k,m��   0w��������^�`���bLM�/��"{�q�Sc\d���\u�|��m�����v�C�c�%{\�a�T�O���u�R1���$�����Qс���W����Q�[�Ϣ��b���YS��$�=ͥZL9����2r�S**�ޚV�Z�&*�M@m"+MZ��@�ڕG�!�u�LAME3.100UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU�gR�_�W��>͐�50dH^��2z牋��&����s��jH>�T`���I�3��`��`W3rLǂ�8�ǣ��<�Z�I�5�¥�Ѽ�z0�vFP�nk5�=5��J˒4gNU�7�DԐ4�����܂!��A���s,����ğt�8���ҧ��m��LΩ
���s4   "�o�~jlcg4Ӏ�)ل``ţ�AE��^B���3#јF�42i��F���. �r%��
�bƈ�O�4��d��Q����a
�q���p�T
[H  :�-��>+p�LT'GJo���a"2�^�����@�I�3�1�:
��]�TL�����Tk)A��bi�� ���W�-�d)�j�D@��\�L�����E�W�Z/�"�i���J���<K�����L\m�/Z�/6��NI\����Y��,���7"�v_7��ALAME3.100UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU�y�A ���"d
�`p�?0��Æ0�?8h  I�@�Z,1q@*��Ŏ�`C��"5
Nt�7�1����9����y�Ji�s@S�b����F�{83NJ$��l�N-TI�A.HKy�0�]e��9l�J�>0�C*�-
T���Ęs,�γ42�I�"a��)��*����& R5 �0I��2   MA#m�?D��%
�� ��-�G3��G�"PA�1���v�/A��\�-!�@�x�1)�!Ta���(�"2�F�t��$��@���U��L�@�DZ�2&���R
&ȁ5�(d��d�N��D1�}[J��HT.��2I@ ��^B�*d�"�!qB��%�0W.-��I@�    ����T�ゃdhd<(���jT�o�8�9�7T������-J`QA;��
����/%ڇH�?��GВ�2I�lS�w��PKaLAME3.100UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU��k�#�6E���K�A�*�\,�BQ�1�!�P� `H%i�y̑���� f"(W#�f0 fL��
GK��CL�p.i��i�&He@���V�f*`d#-��@:�~ 0��� ��t@,Y�M)�a����)x8�Q9�$�HxY$���(&(\:4c�„ !�
 1Q#5�����}0Y��` a�  jg�v@d�$��c�Rb��&�a&pjg,22 CC����h��X(HT�����ȉ�� �����p
W1��)5+1 !����4�H�  0�#0 с%%$% 61`� %U# $2B��)yB��K���,2P A������0�(0�\ 0��-�"�2)R�����
b8F�1b�#���W�k"Ndq�DD
\E1(ί� 9e��0��fv���f�o8~�<٥�bh����=��n��>Ҝ8b-}**LAME3.100���������������������������������������������������������������_� �`��`F!�>`B�ͤg̐x�w�~��`�1># 0�+S( �,@�
"9�0��A�����9������`�X
!�@{)���6!��ә;����D�x
�   @�X�A (&��`�$�`
    e�10Spw0��P#��8�
X��;���ķz�<��t����@5c��p�!����0[��  e� 0E�A״�8�RBy�Y�*�̝���
r�fL�*%�.���@�x��Ɍ�ux5�~��B�#t��!k�a���.��`�{ɀ���������0DmV�U���].
;��6��ڀ�Q���@0(f 6<�
P,�1��hI[X%�"0P�`P(1"�@�v%J�r��yɣg���19=
����C�ԗ��%�Iݦ�?��-K
�@4���ʚ3�6!��v{s,q����Z �&o�Rv��5�����cu�LAME3.100����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������!���D��L��qL"@8�p ��$�/���W)�@�T
@��lE
x�4L*�PF 4aH2��G(g�7F��`N���b�X}��mz�g��c��`q�e�fjk�jY�c@�c�h��o�f��h��e    cظa8�e0�΂�2���`���ĞtLD����mR�A��``*L),���e0��@Sf�@h��]��&�;z�l  ��'*�nnCcXV*���%r�j�Q��/TID��4T˨0.�������`1���0@    ����@�6$�n�SVH�@�_�b
������MZZ�)�V�Q []�Z�%zq��j���ĝ���y���k����8fOÕ<��$v�W
����!�;4��-y�V���d�wm�8L�ŀZ;�༰���cR�w�i�����6a��R�Ue��v6���~8*@�<Ŕ�@�=@̋�$ULAME3.100UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
��}�Y������_����sL1�4��=�DÌ?�LFf��N2��0�
��1��c+0�� q0�13��<A0'��Q�q�d�!��!�q�.�i��  :���@W�
)��>���Ċod)���@ ����8`m@ �d�d�4p ���@   �n�8#
[�@uG������X]��σ�MWb���kƩ�C
�4��~]�$/��;N;� �)��лe�}e�E�H�H+q}��8jЌX�{Y�E"�"G�iP2$� }�X���@����a����8z](��C���֮ٗ��5l�ϼ�^��&dِ0�̚���>�p�PQ']Yڵ��������e��bO0%Lם�2zQ  Ƞ��a*j���2���Uw&��m�����?�H'Q�-}��c-�7��Y��O9�^o�;�LAME3.100UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUb���$L����B�D�"L����̟�|���BH`�`~0�Su��0d
�@(0n3�04ټ�U�
0���1Q�8a�4��t0��30��0'A0#�@0��B0,�0@]��]$�o
$�|����D�^�����0���I���Ĥv���.ည��R   ����ECS�!��p9��0@
55���<��@эx`��.L�5��>F��q�m�Tq��`�l��1�s-EU�^Sd�E
�tSCtxeN�p�2�5I�6�J�c�d��4�3K�xH���V$�y����Jgh�\���qe����~B��   �d��h�{��ܜ�K�f?})�ȓ_!��ge�`�5|@��$ (4)�)��a���=]
�m0`���2���(�_`0Ć{�L    �k"uZ�{��Fhľ�i;)��5�x֫c�z�^)68nm�o<j#tSx���g._
...
```

Service and Controller

```
@Controller('file')
export class FileController {
    constructor(private fileService: FileService) {}

    @Post()
    getFile(): Observable<AxiosResponse<StreamableFile>> {
        return this.fileService.getFile(getFileDto)
    }
}

@Injectable()
export class FileService {
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) { }

  getFile(): Observable<AxiosResponse<StreamableFile>> {
    
    const headersRequest = {
      'OutputFormat': 'audio-16khz-128kbitrate-mono-mp3'
    };
    
    const response = this.httpService.post('https://fileService.com/',
      "fileName",
      {
        headers: headersRequest
      }
    ).pipe(map(response => response.data)); // To fix error (can not convert to JSON)

    return response
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe you need to use 'content-length' header too.

Answer (score 1):

When you receive a streamed file with axios, you need to set the responseType of the HttpService:

```
@Module({
  controllers: [FileController],
  providers: [FileService],
  imports: [   HttpModule.register({
    timeout: 5000,
    maxRedirects: 5,
    responseType: 'arraybuffer', // response type
  }), ConfigModule.forRoot(),]
})
export class FileModule {}
```

and you have to manually set the content-Type of the header:

```
 @Post()
 async getFile(@Response() res: Res) {
     res.setHeader("Content-Type", "audio/mpeg; charset=binary") // set content type and charset
     res.charset = "binary"
     const result = await this.fileService.getFile()
     res.status(HttpStatus.OK).send(result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was stuck on this for hours! That `res.charset` portion seems to be the most important, since axios seems to force `Content-Type` to be `charset=utf-8`, even if you specified it as binary in the header. Also, for anyone who hasn't used `@Response` before, that `res.status().send()` line at the end is vital, otherwise the request will hang forever